# Can raw chicken share a top loading cooler next to RTE food like cheese and also Raw Ground Beef?

Tags: food-safety

The picture is of a top loading cooler ( freezer. Heh..) ground beef on the right. Raw chicken in the middle and RTE cheese on the left [image]

Comment: I bet a health inspector would call that cross contamination in the food prep area.  There is even a gap.  Is this for real?

Comment: Yes this is real 1 of multipul criticals . Like  on the 22nd. No cook showed up and the 2 bosses that are salaried knew. And when i came into work thebnext morning everything wqs still on. And food was out. Units on. Everything hot. Alll.....night.... into the 6am shift when i came in.... livid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That layout is a very bad idea, it would be very easy for the raw chicken to come in contact with the cheese and raw vegetables just to the left of it. Even if the chicken itself doesn't come into contact the chicken juices could drip or spatter.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57627/discussion-on-answer-by-gdd-can-raw-chicken-share-a-top-loading-cooler-next-to-r).